# How to remove highlightBlock strings from generated code

Tags: javascript, regex, blockly

I have a Blockly app that generates the following code as a string.

```
highlightBlock(':_1ku_aN%|65~:kO;KFA');  
start();  
highlightBlock('3TGkH,fdPJ^sYiBQj{uX');   
moveForward();
```

This is the function i use to display the code:

```
function showCode() {
    Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = null;
    var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
    document.getElementById("JSCode").innerText = code;
    console.log(code)
}
```

How can I remove the `highlightBlock('some-id');\n` strings? maybe using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use index of

First split the string based on new line character ie using (;), then push all line in an array using loop check array string contain highlight then split the line use rest of other line you your execution;

```
 code  = code.split(";");
 var newcode = []
 for(var i=0; i<code.length; code++){
  if(code[i].indexOf("highlightBlock") < 0){
newcode.push(code[i]);

   }
}
console.log(newcode);
```

Note: blockly will create id randomly in that semicolon is also part of it please remove that then you wont get any problem in splitting .

its available in blockly.utils core folder